# Janus GridEx: How to filter integers and strings

Tags: c#, gridex

I'm adding a keyword search to a Janus GridEx and thought the easiest method would just be to OR together some filter conditions for each column. Most of the columns are strings and they work fine. If "From" is an integer column, the last line fails when it executes the condition with the error "Input string was not in a correct format." Can I add filter conditions together with some columns of type String and some columns type Integer?

```
        var fromCondition = new GridEXFilterCondition();
        fromCondition.Column = dgDrawings.RootTable.Columns["From"];
        fromCondition.ConditionOperator = ConditionOperator.Contains;
        fromCondition.Value1 = keyword_searchTextBox.Text;

        var toCondition = new GridEXFilterCondition();
        toCondition.Column = dgDrawings.RootTable.Columns["To"];
        toCondition.ConditionOperator = ConditionOperator.Contains;
        toCondition.Value1 = keyword_searchTextBox.Text;

        compositeCondition.AddCondition(LogicalOperator.Or, fromCondition);
        compositeCondition.AddCondition(LogicalOperator.Or, toCondition);

        drawings.RootTable.FilterCondition = compositeCondition;
```

`

Comment: I tried this on GridEX v4.0.14.0 with no issues, irrespective of whether keyword_searchTextBox.Text contains a valid number or not. Perhaps this was a bug in an older version.